# Using bootstrap 3 popover inside table not showing on top of button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Need popover to show users list but its not showing on the top of button.

[image: demonstration]

Here is the jQuery Code:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

Here is C# Code for dynamic buttons inside table rows.

```
<br />
<button title='" + User List + @"' data-original-title='' type='button' class='btn btn-default popovers' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='top' data-html='true' data-content='" + rtnStr + "'>" + Show Users + @"</button>
```

Comment: Are you initialising the popover after adding the buttons dynamically?

Comment: yes, its is initialized when data come from database in table, but after click its show on the left. The property set to top but its goes to left.

Answer (score 0):

This Issue resolved by calculating custom width of the element and find the exact place of the popover.

here is the jQuery Code

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle=popover]', function (e) {
            $('[data-toggle=popover]').not(this).popover('hide');
            var x = ($(window).width() - ($(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth().width()));
            $(this).popover('show');
            $('.popover').css({ "right": (x - 116) + "px", "left": "auto" });
        });
```